# how to terminate inactive websocket connection in passenger

Tags: passenger

Past few days we are struggling with inactive websocket connections. The problem may lay on network level. I would like to ask if there is any switch/configuration option to set timeout for websocket connection for Pushion Passenger in standalone mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably solve this at the application level, because solving it in other layers will be more ugly (less knowledge about websocket).

With Passenger Standalone you could try to set [max_requests](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#--max-requests-max_requests). This should cause application processes to be restarted semi-regularly, and when shutting down a process Passenger should normally abort websocket connections.

If you want more control over the restart period you could also use for example a cron job that executes [rolling restarts](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#--rolling-restarts-rolling_restarts) every so often, which shouldn't be noticeable to users either.

Answer (score 0):

Websockets in Ruby and Passenger (and maybe `node.js` as well) aren't "native" to the server. Instead, your application "hijacks" the socket and controls all the details (timeouts, parsing etc').

This means that a solution must be implemented in the application layer (or whatever framework you're using), since Passenger doesn't keep any information about the socket any more.

I know this isn't the answer you wanted, but it's the fact of the matter.

Some approaches use native websockets where the server controls websocket connections (timeouts, parsing etc', i.e. the Ruby MRI iodine server), but mostly websockets are "hijacked" from the server and the application takes full control and ownership of the connections.